# Why does this code no longer compile when the concept is made variadic?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, language-lawyer, c++20

Let's define the following templates:

```
template<typename> concept C_one = true;
template<typename...> concept C_many = true;

template<bool> struct S { };
```

Now, let's try to use them.
This line compiles:

```
template<typename T = S<C_one<int>>> void f() { }
```

And this one does not:

```
template<typename T = S<C_many<int>>> void f() { }
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<bool <anonymous> > struct S'
```

I noticed that wrapping `C_many<int>` in parentheses fixes the issue, but what is the reason for such seemingly inconsistent syntax? I think the error message isn't very helpful either.
Also, I am aware that this might be a pretty contrived example, because I tried to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Possibly a gcc bug? https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Yd4caxPze. MSVC and Clang seems to not throw an error. Seems to only show with default value of template see:https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hPMoYzP5T

Comment: That's always an option, yeah.

Comment: Definitely a gcc bug. Filed [105268](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105268).